# Change component with props in react router

Tags: reactjs, router

I have login function which get't token from API.

After succesfull POST request I would like to change component with props.
I know how to do it which react DOM, but how can I do it in React Router?

My function with ReactDOM render.

```
 log = (z) => {
      axios.post(apiurl+"api/Auth/Login",
          {Username : this.state.username , Password : this.state.password },
          {headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
          .then(res => {
           ReactDOM.render(<Hometoken = {res.data.token}  />, document.getElementById("root"));
          })
      .catch(error => swal(error.response.data.message));
    }
```

and I've try change it to Redirect

```
log = (z) => {
      axios.post(apiurl+"api/Auth/Login",
          {Username : this.state.username , Password : this.state.password },
          {headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} })
          .then(res => {
           return (<Redirect path="/Home" component={(res) => (<Hometoken = {res.data.token} username = {res.data.nazwa} />)}/>) 
          })
      .catch(error => swal(error.response.data.message));
    }
```

Comment: This seems like an XY problem - so what happens if someone logs in and then refreshes the page? Based on your code, which passes props directly to Components and has no state management, they'd be forced to log back in, would you expect that behaviour? Probably not.

Comment: you are right, but this solution will be useful for me in other function

Answer (score 0):

you can use `props.history.push("/home")` or if in a class component `this.props.history.push("/home")`.

you are going to need to have access to the Router props, so you will need to export your component with the withRouter HOC

export default withRouter(Component)

Comment: the problem isn't only with props, the component doesn't change

Comment: right history.push will redirect you to another URL

Comment: ok, the url is changing but component isn't. is it possible to change component without url adres?

Comment: like what do you want to "change"

Comment: i have a button with onClick to log function. The function with react DOM which I post in question work fine, but i want to add react router to my app and don't know how to get same result with react router

Comment: i want to change component in <div id="root" >

Comment: You will need to do conditional rendering. basically store a piece of state whenever you post something. for example lets say when you post something you set `this.state={posted:false}` to `this.state={posted:true}` now inside where you want to render a component if you posted something, you will put `{this.state.posted && <NewComponent/>}` like this and the NewComponent will only render if this.state.posted is true.